# How can I set validation and default value in proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, buf

I'm trying to add default value to an optional field alongside with validation, but could not find any infos in the docs for multiple conditions in a proto field.
This is the example:

```
optional string date = 1 [(validate.rules).string = { pattern: "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(Z|[+,-][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})"}];
```

After this I'd like to add a [default = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"].

How can I perform this?

Comment: It appears that you're using [Buf](https://buf.build/)'s [`protoc-gen-validate` (PGV)](https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate). You may want to tag this question `[buf]` and considering asking on the PGV repo. Generally validation is distinct post-processing and the value will already have been set. The proto3 default value for string types is `""`. A more idiomatic way to represent time is to use Google's Well-Known Type ([`Timestamp`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp)) although it adds a little complexity too.

Comment: @DazWilkin protoc-gen-validate looks like a noble effort, thank you for the link to it. Though I wish Google would do this; validation is best when it cannot be avoided. Having validation methods that can be called is pretty good, but having the serialise / parse methods validate whilst they're serialising / parsing is far better. That way, duff data never makes it as far as the application; it's cut out, excess memory won't get allocated (in the case of maliciously long strings, say). Still, it looks like a good improvement on stock protobufs.